# How to decide when to update, delete and insert

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa for creating services. I have to do insert, update and delete operation on one save button. for save and update I am using repository save method in my code. For deciding need to do update or insert I am checking count of records.

If I am sending one record then I am successfully able to do save and update operations.

But my problem is that when I am sending two record which already present is db
that need to go for update. but In my situation I am checking count of record so its going for save instead of update.

Can any one tell me what condition need to check more then it will go for update ? Or 
Tell me any another way for to decide when to go for update,when to go for insert and when to go for delete?

**RoomInvestigatorMappingService class**

```
public String updatePiDetails(List<PiDetails> roomInvestMapping) {

    List<RoomInvestigatorMapping> currentRecord = new ArrayList<RoomInvestigatorMapping>();
    for (PiDetails inputRecorObj : roomInvestMapping) {
        currentRecord = roomInvestigatorMappingRepo.findByNRoomAllocationId(inputRecorObj.getnRoomAllocationId());
    }
    int currentRecordCount = currentRecord.size();
    int inputRecordCount = roomInvestMapping.size();

    // update existing record
    if (inputRecordCount == currentRecordCount) {
        for (PiDetails inputObject : roomInvestMapping) {
            for (RoomInvestigatorMapping currentRecordObj : currentRecord) {
                currentRecordObj.nInvestigatorId = inputObject.getnInvestigatorId();
                currentRecordObj.nPercentageAssigned = inputObject.getnPercentageAssigned();
                currentRecordObj.nRoomAllocationId = inputObject.getnRoomAllocationId();
                roomInvestigatorMappingRepo.saveAll(currentRecord);
            }
        }
    }

    //insert new record
    if (inputRecordCount > currentRecordCount) {
        for (PiDetails inputObject : roomInvestMapping) {
            RoomInvestigatorMapping investObj = new RoomInvestigatorMapping();
            investObj.nInvestigatorId = inputObject.getnInvestigatorId();
            investObj.nRoomAllocationId = inputObject.getnRoomAllocationId();
            investObj.nPercentageAssigned = inputObject.getnPercentageAssigned();
            roomInvestigatorMappingRepo.save(investObj);
        }
    }
    return "sucessfully";
}
```

**RoomInvestigatorMappingRepository interface**

```
@Query("select roomInvestMapping from RoomInvestigatorMapping as roomInvestMapping where nRoomAllocationId=?1")
List<RoomInvestigatorMapping> findByNRoomAllocationId(Integer nRoomAllocationId);
```

**Json Input**

```
[
  {
    "nInvestigatorId": 911294,
    "nPercentageAssigned": 50,
    "nRoomAllocationId": 1
  },
  {
    "nInvestigatorId": 911294,
    "nPercentageAssigned": 50,
    "nRoomAllocationId": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the unique id (primary key) for the RoomInvestigatorMapping, this vital for doing the right update. Your for-loop in the beginning is plain wrong since currentRecord will always be set from the last PiDetails in your input list and all other will be ignored.

Comment: There is no update in spring-data-jpa.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`CrudRepository.existsById(ID id)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#existsById-ID-)

The documentation says:

> Returns whether an entity with the given id exists.

Comment: existsById(ID id) using this method at a time I can check only one record how to check like (id1 or id2 or id3.....etc)

Comment: Why don't you want to use the existing method?